# Get rid of a TimerJob/Feature which throws an exception

Tags: 2010, visual-studio-2012, custom-timer-job

I created a TimerJob which is activated upon Feature activation. Because I didn't know better, I forgot to add an public default constructor and now I always get this exception: "*Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Lists.JobTimerReminder cannot be deserialized because it does not have a public default constructor.*" when I want to retract the solution (or try to disable the Feature, or even when I run 'Get-SPTimerJob' in the Management Shell).
I cannot work on and redeploy my project (via Visual Studio) because it has to be retracted beforehand.

How can I get rid of this thing?

Comment: Run.   **Uninstall-spsolution .... -force           **Remove-spsolution .... - force.     You can also do. Get-sptimerjob | where-object { $_.name -like "*...*"} | % { $_.Delete }

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I get the error message from above on every single command you posted (I already tried Uninstall and Remove before). [...] is the Name of my custom Timerjob class

Comment: I even removed the whole SiteCollection and created a new one, but this Timerjob seems to be very stubborn... I also tried replacing the assembly via gacutil. I am very desperate atm...

Comment: Changing site collections won't help as timerjobs are stored @ the farm level. Look into what the default constructors are and try to use those as they should still be apart of the timerjob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after trying ever single uninstall command, cleans, redeployments, Replacing the assembly with a fixed one via Gacutil, Several iisresets, deletion of site collection and so on, it finally worked after restarting my development machine.
I *think* replacing the Assembly in the GAC did the job (+ restarting, otherwise it still wouldn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the dll in GAC and `IISRESET` did the trick for me :-)

Comment: could you please explain which dll you meant?

Comment: dll for the timer job

Comment: is it also named like the job or the solution?

Comment: it will have the project name not solution name